# UIImage not being saved in Documents directory and killing the app

Tags: ios, uiimage

I get the UIImage from a UIImagePickerController, and I save it like so:

```
- (void) saveImageLocally:(UIImage *)image {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",@"A5UserAvatar"]];

    if (![imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to cache image data to disk");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"the cachedImagedPath is %@", imagePath);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imagePath forKey:@"AvatarKey"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

And I can immediately after access it without problem like this:

```
- (UIImage *) getLocalImage {
    NSString *path = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AvatarKey"];
    NSLog(@"PATH FOR IMAGE IS %@", path);
    if (path != nil) {
        return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    } else {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.gif"];
    }
}
```

The above code returns the saved UIImage with no problem at all.

The thing is, when I kill the app and start it up again, it the image is not found!
I'm currently using Xcode 6 building for iOS 7 and 8. I know this problem is inevitable in simulator, but I'm experiencing it on a live device also.

(see [Xcode 6 keeps renaming my app's directory in iOS8 simulator after each run.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233386/xcode-6-keeps-renaming-my-apps-directory-in-ios8-simulator-after-each-run))

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong or if there's another way of just storing any image as a file in the app to use like an avatar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are saving the full path instead of the path relative to the Documents folder. You can't save full paths since the app path can change.

You want something like this:

```
- (void) saveImageLocally:(UIImage *)image {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",@"A5UserAvatar"];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    if (![imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to cache image data to disk");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"the cachedImagedPath is %@", imagePath);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:filename forKey:@"AvatarKey"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

- (UIImage *) getLocalImage {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filename = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AvatarKey"];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSLog(@"PATH FOR IMAGE IS %@", path);
    if (path != nil) {
        return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    } else {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.gif"];
    }
}
```

Comment: The above does not seem to work, the app prints out a path when loading the image, but killing it and running it again, it prints out a different path and of course, it cannot find the file.

Comment: When saving the image the path is: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D38345C3-473A-485F-A90C-3890736DDD54/Documents/A5UserAvatar.png



Now killing the app, and the path it attempts to read from is:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B5595689-10DA-4BBA-B47E-8E27EDE38AE4/Documents/A5UserAvatar.png

Comment: Right. When you rebuild and run your app it is moving the app to the new folder. But the contents should be moved too unless you are deleting the app from the device between builds.

Comment: Running the app from the last build, straight from the phone without rebuilding. It saves it fine first time, but I seem to get the same effect when killing it and relaunching it again.

Comment: The path shouldn't be changing between runs unless you do another build and run from Xcode.

Comment: Did another test without rebuilding. It spits out the same path both times, but the second time, the image is still nil.

Comment: I discovered that the console shows: a Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.goodyear.menlo" before the call to [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]