# Application folder name changes every time i run in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, base-path, nshomedirectory

Whenever I restart my application it's folder name in finder is changed from

> 09323D3F-D371-4556-ABA3-BD23AF487F12

to

> E771BBEC-ACC6-489C-B7C1-B5FF11004CB2/

`NSHomeDirectory()` is changing everytime I run the app in simulator.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233386/xcode-6-keeps-renaming-my-apps-directory-in-ios8-simulator-after-each-run

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't save the full path, but just the directory and file name to the images.
Since this behaviour is new in iOS 8 and will happen on a real device.

Comment: It happens on a real device.

Comment: @Cy-4AH, I had some issue with app update have different paths.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have this link in your code `NSDocumentationDirectory`  change it into `NSDocumentDirectory`

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Answer (score 0):

save your file path like as follows :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]lastPathComponent]];
```