# App Home Folder Constantly Change IOS

Tags: ios

when I use writeTofile code and then after restart application file is not found!
i traced

```
NSLog("%@",NSHomeDirectory()
```

and it is constantly changing for example first opening app
the output:

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/**42ED7B5A-FB4A-4532-8CBF-7C7E5DA46A8F**

second one is :

var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/**3AD0B8BB-F15B-4290-ABD5-5E0D1319C657**

I use these codes to save my videoData

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strVideoName];

            [videoData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

so they are different and file not found

what should i do to save my videoData?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 keeps renaming my app's directory in iOS8 simulator after each run.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233386/xcode-6-keeps-renaming-my-apps-directory-in-ios8-simulator-after-each-run)

Comment: i can't see any solution @Babar

Comment: The file is moved. How are you trying to find it? Make sure you are not storing absolute paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use absolue paths... Use something like this

```
NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]lastPathComponent]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This UDID in the path to your app changes on every update or dev build you install. This is a folder structure change in iOS8 and above. You should store relative paths to your files and use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` method to retrieve your Documents/Caches, etc. folders and append your saved relative paths.

Comment: I use already
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *path2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strThumnailName];