# applicationDocumentsDirectory changes on build

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've created a new swift project and ticked the box for 'use core data'. I've noticed every time i build to my device my data has been cleared from the database. Tracing through the code i noticed that the default set-up for core data which xcode adds into the app delegate has a different url everytime i run the app:

```
line in app del:
let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Testo.sqlite")

first execution
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3EA9BE17-223E-4FA9-A8AB-E30161B39BF5/Documents/Testo.sqlite

second execution
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FA0F72CF-B6BD-4ADA-AE19-D71A3189DAA0/Documents/Testo.sqlite

third execution
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BD20A689-0D02-4353-BB1E-14857496D2E9/Documents/Testo.sqlite
```

Im guessing this is why my data keeps disapearing. Is there a way to prevent this so it doesnt look like my data is being cleared.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 keeps renaming my app's directory in iOS8 simulator after each run.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233386/xcode-6-keeps-renaming-my-apps-directory-in-ios8-simulator-after-each-run)

Comment: Does look like it might be the same thing but no solution given. What path should be used so i dont loose all my data?

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, `NSDocumentDirectory` changes on every build. However, files inside the documents directory are copied to the "new" location before each run. So I don't think this is why your data keeps disappearing. Have you tried looking inside those directories to see if `Testo.sqlite` is actually there? And if so, does it contain any data?

Side Note:

Apple does not recommend that you store your database files in the `NSDocumentDirectory`. Instead, setup your SQLite store to be in the Application Library:

`var appDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)`

For future reference, here's some documentation from Apple about the different directories:

[iOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4)