# Where does React-Native AsyncStorage save data on disk using iPhone Simulator?

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, asyncstorage

Using IOS Simulator, where does React-Native AsyncStorage save the data on disk ?

I am using IOS Simulator version 10.0 and running IOS 10.2 and react-native 0.40.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React Native async storage data is inside Documents folder of you application sandbox. For react-native 0.40.0 it is `Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1/manifest.json`.

Path to sandbox folder for iOS Simulator (Xcode 8.2) is: `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE_ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APP_ID}`

To find `DEVICE_ID` you can use `xcrun simctl list` from terminal.
Since your application gets new `APP_ID` on each run, you can't easily find it. I simple list all files inside Application and get most recently updated. See [Xcode 6 keeps renaming my app's directory in iOS8 simulator after each run.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25233386/2266462) and related for other solutions.

Comment: Thanks !  To find my ```APP_ID```, I have used one of these solutions : http://superuser.com/questions/147027/how-can-i-sort-the-output-of-ls-by-last-modified-date to pin point which one it is.

Comment: is there a way if we can set other location for AsyncStorage ? because I want DocumentDir folder sharable to the user over itunes and as I keep some login details into AsyncStorage, Its the last thing I want it seen by my app users.

Comment: This may be a bit late - but to @AmitBravo - don't store any sensitive information inside the AsyncStorage. Store sensitive details inside the keychain (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) - store everything else inside AsyncStorage.

Comment: In case someone is interested only in previewing the stored data, the following command prints the `manifest.json` files that were modified in the last hour
`find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator -mtime -1 -name manifest.json -exec cat {} \; -exec echo  \;`

You can change the `-mtime` parameter if you want older files

Comment: To find device ID, run the simulator, then run `xcrun simctl list | grep Booted`

Comment: `manifest.json` doesnt contain _all_ data! There are other files within `RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1` , with hex names and no file extension, which contain huge amounts of my json data.

Comment: @lance.dolan Yes, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.55-stable/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.m#L164 and following code to learn about exact format.

Comment: also for more comprehensive, the ```Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1/manifest.json```file is located on:
```~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/${DEVICE_ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/${APP_ID}/Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1```

then you can cat the file:
`cat manifest.json`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other helpful comments and answers, let me summarize how to inspect AsyncStorage:

First, `cd` into the Async directory.

```
cd `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted $BUNDLE_ID data`/Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1
```

Then review the manifest:

```
jq < manifest.json
```

Then to pretty-print a non-null value  in the manifest:

```
jq '."somekey"|fromjson' < manifest.json
```

For `null` values, find the file that has the value:

```
md5 -s "otherkey"
# 90f5ba064f8280d4c94b1f0b1a85a79e
```

Then pretty-print that file:

```
jq < 90f5ba064f8280d4c94b1f0b1a85a79e
```

I have also shared this in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/chetstone/df3250abc7868fe5087e9f0b83a316d6)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to see the AsyncStorage in console as i prefer

you can use this code :

```
export var getAllKeysAndValues = async () => {
  try {
    // Retrieve all keys
    const keys = await asyncStorage.getAllKeys();

    // Create an object to store key-value pairs
    const keyValuePairs = {};

    // Loop through each key and fetch its corresponding value
    await Promise.all(keys.map(async key => {
      const value = await asyncStorage.getItem(key);
      keyValuePairs[key] = value; // Store key-value pair
    }));

    console.log('All keys and values:', keyValuePairs);
    return keyValuePairs; // You can return the object if needed
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting all keys and values:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```